# EJS and js: nested variables

Tags: nested, ejs

This is what I'm tring to do: use a ejs variable in a if condition.
In the example "errors" and "idName" are sent from the server.
(I'm doing a validation with express-validator and I have to show the error)

```
<% if(errors && errors[<%= idName %>]) { %>
```

It doesn't work. I've also tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">         
      let errCard=errors[<%= idName %>] 
</script> 
<% if(errors && errCard) { %>        
      <span class="text-red-500 text-sm"><%= errCard.msg %</span>  
<% } %>
```

in this case the error is: "errCard is not defined".

Answer (score 0):

The following code works:

```
<% if(errors && errors[locals.idName]) { %>
<p class="text-center text-red-500 text-sm -mt-4"><%=errors[locals.idName].msg %></p>
<% } %>
```